# Why changes made in QtDesigner form not shown in QGIS plugin gui?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2, qt-designer

I have created a plugin in QGIS 2.10.1.

After making some modifications in the ui file in Qt Designer and reloaded the plugin or restarted QGIS or restarted the pc these are not incorporated. I cannot understand why, since till now this has been working. The only differences with other times is that before the modifications I had made a copy of the the plugin folder (copied folder), pasted it on another folder on my computer, then erased the initial plugin folder from .qgis2\python\plugins\ folder and re-pasted the copied folder inside the .qgis2\python\plugins\ folder.

Due to my limited relevant knowledge, I thought to compile again the resources file, but again no result.

Also, I applied a make deploy (when trying to change the icon) so maybe this has to do with this.  That' s all the actions I have taken.

Why are changes made in the QtDesigner form not shown in QGIS plugin GUI?

But if the folder that conatins the modified ui, is copied and pasted on another folder in my computer, erased from the .qgis2\python\plugins\ folder in wich the folder that conatins the modified ui is pasted, when running again the QGIS I can see the changes. But again if I make new changes nor plugin reload neither restarting QGIS is working. I have to follow again the procedure I just described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to compile the UI file as well as any resources (.qrc) file.

Most plugins have a xxx.ui an a corresponding xxx.py file, example:

https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin/tree/master/openlayers

has `ui_about_dialog.ui` and `ui_about_dialog.py` - you make the .py from the .ui using `pyuic4`, normally driven by a Makefile rule. Again, that plugin has the following rule in the Makefile:

```
%.py : %.ui
    pyuic4 -o $@ $<
```